# MS SQL update table column with a value which will fit between time range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: 'Job execution' with Job start and end datetime and 
second tables 'Measurements' with sensors probes datetime

I need to update the table 'Measurements' with related Job Nr from 'Job execution'

[Table Measurements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP8Ff.png)
[Table Job execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0K5m.png)

Comment: What's stopping you to do the `update`? Have you tried something so far and got an error?

Answer (score 0):

Vague question.  Doing some guessing:   (untested)

```
update m
set JOB_handle=j.JOB_handle, JOB_Handle_start=j.JOB_startallocdatetime, JOB_Handle_end=j.JOB_endallocdatetime
from measurements m
inner join job j
   on j.JOB_startallocdatetime <= m.timestamp and j.JOB_endallocdatetime >= m.timestamp
```

Basically determining the correct job based on the timestamp of the measurements